# Why doesn't the following code run on my computer, on an online execution environment, it runs perfectly. I use python 3.7.0

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, beautifulsoup

i expect a data frame with data but when i run it i get an empty data frame, when i run it  here: https://www.pythonanywhere.com/try-ipython/ i get a result. What am i doing wrong?

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag
import requests
import re

data = []
s = "https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ACYBGNQ8Fi1dsaisfvundg1DuQk-01zamg:1573888738693&q=list+of+dry+cleaners+and+Launderettes+in+Ireland&npsic=0&rflfq=1&rlha=0&rllag=53813949,-7898686,117899&tbm=lcl&ved=2ahUKEwip_L25mO7lAhVQx4UKHe7lDYoQjGp6BAgKED0&tbs=lrf:!1m4!1u3!2m2!3m1!1e1!1m4!1u2!2m2!2m1!1e1!2m1!1e2!2m1!1e3!3sIAE,lf:1,lf_ui:2&rldoc=1#rlfi=hd:;si:;mv:[[54.07819766551908,-5.352135778124989],[52.2676036128125,-10.548668981249989],null,[53.182453596104196,-7.950402379687489],8];start:"

for x in range(0, 2):
    user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36'
    headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent}
    res=requests.get(s + str(x), headers=headers)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(res.text, features='lxml')
    listings=soup.findAll(class_='cXedhc')

    for listing in listings:
        listing_title = listing.find('div', {'class':'dbg0pd'})

        listing_details = listing.find('span', {'class':'rllt__details lqhpac'})
        full_dict={'Title': listing_title, 'details': listing_details}
        data.append(full_dict)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. If I run in jupyter (laptop) I get results though I prefer to run with .text rather than returning node html.

Comment: @Qharr i don't understand

Comment: I mean I can run on local machine and get output so don’t think it is the code per se.

Comment: So the problem could be my computer or my python?

Comment: No error messages at all? What environment are you running it in locally?

Comment: No error at all. i use IDLE Python 32 bit

Comment: I have seen the error, I hadn't updated one of the libraries